# trouble with workflow when saving a record

Tags: python, odoo, workflow

I'm working on a workflow on `audit` module, I added the workflow into the view as follows:

in `audit.xml`:

```
<header>
<button name="button_close" string="Close" states="opened" icon="gtk-jump-to" type="object"/>
<button name="button_open" string="Open" states="draft" type="object"/>
<button name="button_validate" string="Validate" states="done" icon="gtk-jump-to" type="object"/>
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" select="1" readonly="1" clickable="True"/>
```

in `audit.py` I have:

```
'state': fields.selection(
        [
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('opened', 'Opened'),
            ('done', 'Closed'),
            ('validated','Validated')
        ],
        'State',
    ),
_defaults = {
    'state': 'draft'
}
def button_open(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, _("Audit created"), context=context)
    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'opened'})
def button_close(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """When Audit is closed, post a message to followers' chatter."""
    self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, _("Audit closed"), context=context)
    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'done'})
def button_validate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """When Audit is validated, post a message to followers' chatter."""
    self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, _("Audit validated"), context=context)
    return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'validated'})
```

I want the state stays as it is in the workflow but when I save a new record the state changes automatically to `'validated'`.

Comment: set validated as the default , or override the write

Comment: how can I override the write?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
 # write your logic here

 return super(my_model_name, self).create(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'validated'}, context=context)
```